# How can i query the one last register for each field in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains many registers from many clients I.E.:

```
CLIENT 1- 22/09/2014
CLIENT 1- 19/09/2014
CLIENT 1- 10/09/2014
CLIENT 2- 15/09/2014
CLIENT 2- 20/09/2014
```

How can I query the table in order to obtain only the last register for each client:

```
CLIENT 1- 22/09/2014
CLIENT 2- 20/09/2014
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select client, max(register) 
from your_table
group by client
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select client, max(register) 
from your_table
group by client, register
having max(register) = register
```